# What does health_percentage measure in Github API community metrics?

Tags: github-api

Github provides an API call to get [community metrics](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/community/). But no where can I find any explanation to what does the field `health_percentage` represent. I tried calling on several projects, and got `null`s or 0-100 (duh :)), but I can't tell what this number shows.

Can anyone point me to an explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Community health is the [checklist for the presence of the following files](https://help.github.com/articles/about-community-profiles-for-public-repositories/) :

- Description
- README
- CODE_OF_CONDUCT
- CONTRIBUTING
- LICENSE
- ISSUE_TEMPLATE and PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE

The health percentage is just the percentage of progress through this checklist.

[An example](https://github.com/facebook/react/community) of a project which has all those files (health_percentage of 100%) :

[image]

Comment: Makes sense now. Thanks!